# ListView LayoutTemplate does not show when empty asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have an `<asp:ListView>` but for some reason the LayoutTemplate section does not show when the list is empty, although the `<EmptyDataTemplate>` section shows. The LayoutTemplate contains the headers for the table, and I want to show an empty table when there are no items in the datasource, not just the content of EmptyDataTemplate.

If there is no choice I will copy the LayoutTemplate into EmptyDataTemplate but it seems stupid to have to do this. Ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.emptydatatemplate.aspx):

> The empty template is displayed in a
>   `ListView` control when the data source
>   that is bound to the control does not
>   contain any records and the
>   `InsertItemPosition` property is set to
>   `InsertItemPosition.None`. The template
>   is rendered instead of the
>   `LayoutTemplate` template. If the
>   `InsertItemPosition` property is set to
>   a value other than
>   `InsertItemPosition.None`, the
>   `EmptyDataTemplate` template is not
>   rendered.

the key words here are "...the template is rendered **instead** of the `LayoutTemplate` template..."

So I think, you have to copy the `LayoutTemplate` into the `EmptyDataTemplate` template.

Comment: Indeed. For tables that render their rows in ListViews, I just put the header tags outside the ListView, and the LayoutTemplate just holds the ItemPlaceholder now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put your   into a User Control (.acsx).   Then include it in the layout template and the empty template... and it will feel less stupid since you can still manage it in one spot.    I know how you feel about copying the same code...seems like something a 5th grader would do.  Using a control is a more grown up approach.

Answer (score 0):

In a very simple way you can get both your headers and a message saying that there were no data.

You make your `LayoutTemplate` like the following idea:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a header</td>
      <td>another header</td>
      <td>third header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
      <td colspan="3"
        There is no data!
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

Notice that the `tr` that is the placeholder (marked by id="itemPlaceholder") actually contains something. It contains what should be shown when there is no data. Then, in code behind, you set the `<EmptyTemplate>` to be equal to the `<LayoutTemplate>` (so that you have only one such template to maintain). I do it like this:

```
Private Sub lvwThings_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvwThings.Init
    lvwThings.EmptyDataTemplate = lvwThings.LayoutTemplate
End Sub
```

The logic then is as follows:

When there **is** data, i.e. when the actual `<LayoutTemplate>` is used, the whole `<tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">`, with the `td` and text it contains, will be replaced by the `<ItemTemplate>`.

But, when there is **no** data, i.e. when the `<EmptyTemplate>` is used (instead of the `<LayoutTemplate>`), nothing inside the `<EmptyTemplate>`is replaced, so everything is shown as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem when you have InsertItemTemplate with EmptyDataTemplate.
Arrcording to MS docs, that's you can't have both. So I decided to create new  tag in InsertItemTemplate.
You can preview my example code here.

```
   <InsertItemTemplate>
        <% if (CheckEmptyTable())
            { %>
              <tr> 
                 <td colspan="6">No data founds。</td>
              </tr>
        <% } %>
         // Your insert template input here 
        <tr style="">
          
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

My result image:
[image]