# how to show header row either listview has data or not?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, listview

I have a list view and i want to add a header row in it which will come when the listview has data or not. in each and every condition i want it there. I have used LayOut Template to do so but its showing the Header row only if the listview has data.Then i tried EmptydataTemplate, Its showing the header row but now the button in it is not working.
My code is

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upViewSchedule" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListView ID="lstuser" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="trItem" DataKeyNames="id"
                OnItemDataBound="lstuser_ItemDataBound">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table cellspacing="0">
                        <tr class="hdrRowColor1">
                            <td align="left">
                                &nbsp;name
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                salary
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                address
                            </td>
                            <td align="left" style="border-right: 1px solid #6398cc">
                                Actions
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="OddRowColor">
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drphdrname" runat="server" Width="120px">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <ajaxCtrl:CascadingDropDown ID="csddrphdrName" runat="server" TargetControlID="drpname"
                                    Category="Name" ServicePath="~/Resources/WebService.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetName">
                                </ajaxCtrl:CascadingDropDown>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtaddress" runat="server" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td width="50px" class="last">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnHdrAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ThemeNew/Images/add_new.png"
                                    OnClick="imgBtnHdrAdd_Click" ToolTip="Add user." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trItem" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr class='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Container.DataItemIndex % 2) ? "OddRowColor" : "EvenRowColor" %>'>
                        <td align="left" width="138px">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpname" runat="server" Width="120px">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCreatedBY" Text='<%# Eval("CreatedBy") %>' runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            <ajaxCtrl:CascadingDropDown ID="casddrpContacts" runat="server" TargetControlID="drpname"
                                Category="name" ServicePath="~/Resources/WebService.asmx" ServiceMethod="Getuser">
                            </ajaxCtrl:CascadingDropDown>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="138px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("salary") %>' Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" width="138px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address") %>' Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left" class="last">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ThemeNew2/images/update.png"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnClick="imgBtnEdit_Click" ToolTip="Update user" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ThemeNew/Images/delete.png"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this user ?');"
                                ToolTip="Delete user" OnClick="imgBtnDelete_OnClick" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table cellspacing="0">
                        <tr class="hdrRowColor1">
                            <td align="left">
                                &nbsp;name
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                salary
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                address
                            </td>
                            <td align="left" style="border-right: 1px solid #6398cc">
                                Actions
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="OddRowColor">
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drphdrname" runat="server" Width="120px">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <ajaxCtrl:CascadingDropDown ID="csddrphdrName" runat="server" TargetControlID="drpname"
                                    Category="Name" ServicePath="~/Resources/WebService.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetName">
                                </ajaxCtrl:CascadingDropDown>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtaddress" runat="server" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td width="50px" class="last">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnHdrAdd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/ThemeNew/Images/add_new.png"
                                    OnClick="imgBtnHdrAdd_Click" ToolTip="Add user." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="trItem" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

my Code behind code is

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BIndAddress();
        // BindRoleDrop();
        drpAddress.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Area", ""));
        drpRoom.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Room", ""));
        ViewState["sortCol"] = "tblUser.id";
        ViewState["sortDir"] = "Desc";
        ViewState["nmbr"] = 1;
        BindData(ViewState["sortCol"].ToString(), ViewState["sortDir"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["nmbr"]), 7999);

    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Visible = false;

    }

}
```

And one thing more please let me know how can i apply validations on these.

Comment: How does the code behind method `imgBtnHdrAdd_Click` look?

Comment: Sir its just calling the insert method nothing else in that.That will work on when it will fire and that is actual prob its not firing

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500296/listview-layouttemplate-does-not-show-when-empty-asp-net

Comment: Sir i have also done that but the main problem is BUTTON CLICK in firing.

Comment: Did you also try what commenter Graham suggested in the answer to the question that podiluska linked to (move header row outside of ListView)? Based on a quick test i did locally, the ListView is in a state where child controls cannot raise events if the ListView is showing the EmptyDataTemplate.

Comment: yes exactly what happens with me do you have solution for this prob if yes please let me know too

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing locally. I found that if I have a button in the EmptyDataTemplate it's OnClick event will fire as expected as long as you do not modify the state of the ListView before the event fires.

I'm guessing therefore that you have some code that modifies the state (re-binds it for instance) of the ListView which runs before the `imgBtnHdrAdd_Click` event handler for the button in question.

The Page_Load method would have been the primary suspect, but based on your code it is properly checking for `!IsPostBack`.

I'm assuming that it is the call to `BindData` that is used for setting databinding the ListView. Look for other places in you code behind where that method is called and verify that none of those places are being run before the event handler for the button.

Comment: That is already checked. I have checked this first of all but its fine there is no method called to bind the Listview before event

Comment: @Visions And nothing else touches the ListView either before the button event handler should run? Does it even cause a PostBack at all? If nothing touches the ListView then I'm out of ideas unless the ListView itself is inside some control that changes state...

Comment: I have done it with some other way now. I have tried a lot but i don't know why that was not worked for me now i have Paste the content of layout template to a panel, when there is no data then i will display that panel otherwise normal listview.